# How Do I Port Foward A Terraria Server?

Tags: terraria, server-administration

How do I port foward a Terraria server? I have been trying to set it up for a long time but I can't. People say its very hard, but some say it is easy. Thanks!

Comment: same way as you'd do a minecraft or anything else server. Besides manually doing ports, you could also use the less savory Hamachi/Tuungle options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open your router’s configuration web-page, then enter your computer’s IP address in the port-forwarding section and specify 7777 for the port (Terraria’s default).

Answer (score 7):

It will depend on what make and model of router you have.

Once you have determined the make and model of your router, you will need to open its configuration page in a web-browser (hopefully you have some experience with since you would at the very least need to change the password). Then find the *Port Forwarding* page (it may also be called *Virtual Application* or something similar).

Then you’ll need to create an entry for Terraria, specifying the IP address of your computer and the port to forward which in the case of Terraria, is 7777 (it [used to be 31337](http://boards.portforward.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1221)).

One thing to be wary of is that you will need to configure your router and computer to use a static IP address because if you use a dynamic IP, then depending on the order in which your computer and other devices request an address from the router, you could end up forwarding to the wrong thing (for example to your phone instead of your laptop).

You can get an easy to follow, [visual guide at portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Terraria/default.htm). If you run into trouble, check the forums for threads about [port-forwarding Terraria](http://boards.portforward.com/search.php?keywords=terraria) where you’ll find some useful threads (like [this one](http://boards.portforward.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3663)). Of course you can also register an account there to request specific help if your circumstances are unusual and nothing works.

It may seem like a daunting task, but it is actually fairly simple. If it does turn out to be difficult, you can always try a [program](http://portforward.com/software.htm) to automate the process for you.

Comment: Very detailed and easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to port forward a Terraria Server:

1. Open your router's configuration webpage.
2. Find out your computer's IP address.
3. Go to the port-forwarding section.
4. Enter your computer's IP address.
5. For the port, enter in 7777.

I hope you find this useful!